# Как Google определяет роботов?

Tags: google-search

Всем привет. Интересует вопрос: по каким признакам гугл определяет скрипты, боты и т.д. ? Нужно обойти блокировку гугл для скрэпинга данных.

Comment: Кроме гугла этого ни кто не знает.

Comment: @visman, спасибо, капитан очевидность

Comment: Правильно вам @visman ответил. Не стоит сюда приходить с очевидными вопросами.

Comment: я слышал с помощью нейро сетей, это первая зацепка, собирайте дальше))

Comment: Интересно, а что вы собрались скрэпить у Гугла-то? :) Неужели свое "левое" зеркало Ютуба создать хотите? Или Google Cloud Storage? А вообще, у Гугла кроме традиционных способов (разные проверки при анализе конкретного запроса) есть еще и анализ статистики в целом, называется bigdata, и если вы сделали 1, 2, 3, 100, 1000 запросов и они прошли успешно, но имеют различие от нормальных (свежие аккаунты, один и тот же UA...) - то радость будет недолгой, bigdata либо забанит вас, либо восстановит справедливость иным способом (в Ютубе и Поиске это пессимизация того, что вы накрутили).

Comment: А еще у Гугла адская капча Recaptcha. В общем, ботоводы без толстого кошелька (обычно наивность свойственна гражданам Украины, но бывают и России, например) не имеют никаких шансов - хотя их квадратно-гнездовое мышление (особенно украинцев) не позволяет им это понять, им кажется, что проблема в человеке, и надо найти другого, который реализует сложнейшую задачу дешево и хорошо.

Comment: @rou1997, не угадали :)

Comment: @RezvanovMaxim А я и не собираюсь гадать. В таких случаях даже от подробного ТЗ толку мало, так как нет информации о потрохах самого сайта, а тут гадать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути `USER AGENT`, HTTP HEADER(http заголовок)

Пример: (каждая строка это пример USER AGENT HEADER)

```
AdsBot-Google (+http://www.google.com/adsbot.html)
AdsBot-Google-Mobile (+http://www.google.com/mobile/adsbot.html) Mozilla (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3 0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari
Apache-HttpClient/4.5 (Java/1.8.0_60)
eSyndiCat Bot
facebookexternalhit/1.1
facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
Google favicon
Googlebot-Image/1.0
GuzzleHttp/6.1.0 curl/7.26.0 PHP/5.5.29-1~dotdeb+7.1
GuzzleHttp/6.1.0 curl/7.35.0 PHP/5.6.14-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
Java/1.4.1_04
Java/1.8.0_60
LinksMasterRoBot/0.01 (http://www.linksmaster.ru)
LinkStats Bot
ltx71 - (http://ltx71.com/)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.0; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; archive.org_bot; Wayback Machine Live Record; +http://archive.org/details/archive.org_bot)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; CNCat/4.2; +http://www.cn-software.com/en/cncat/robot/)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; CNCat/4.2; +http://www.vipwords.com/en/cncat/robot/)
```

Строки `USER AGENT` ботов взяты https://akuma.su/blog/spisok-user-agent-botov.html ,сами знания из головы.

Выдержка из вики что такое `USER AGENT`

```
При посещении веб-сайта клиентское приложение обычно посылает веб-серверу информацию о себе. Это текстовая строка, являющаяся частью HTTP запроса, начинающаяся с User-agent: или User-Agent:, и обычно включающая такую информацию, как название и версию приложения, операционную систему компьютера и язык.
```

Источник: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Agent

Comment: Спасибо, за наводку. Но по моему дело не только в user agent

Comment: Роботы давно уже ходят с ua реальных браузеров (кроме может быть древних китайских, во всяком случае ip из китая).

Comment: толи ответ не в тему. толи вопрос задан неверно...

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, скорее вопрос некорректный